# changing the color of a part of text in stylus css?

Tags: css, stylus

i want to change the color of only one word in string of text using stylus i.e.

```
#copy
   h1 Our new site will be ready soon..
```

the stylus code is

```
  h1
   font-weight bold
   color white
```

i just want to change the color of the first letter in the h1 phrase "Our" into yellow
how could i achieve that in stylus, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the [:first-letter](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-firstletter) selector:

```
h1:first-letter
    color: yellow
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/scumah/7x9VU/) a fiddle with an example.

Answer (score 9):

The css selector "first-letter" selector is a good option.

If you want to change other letters or parts of text as per your example, use a span with its own style, e.g.

```
<h1><span style="color:yellow">O</span>ur <span style="color:blue">new</span> website</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be done by making use of [Pseudo-elements](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7x9VU/1/)